# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111 when selecting "org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point" in native query

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I want to implement a projection for messages with a calculated distance using native query

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "messages")
data class Message(
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  var id: Int?=null,
  var message: String,
  var userName: String,
  var location: Point? = null
)
```

my projecting interface

```
interface FoundMessage {
  var id: Int
  var message: String
  var location: Point
  var userName: String
  var distance: Float
}
```

my repository

```
interface MessageRepository : CrudRepository<Message, Int> {

  @Query(
      "SELECT id,message,location,user_name as \"userName\", st_distance(messages.location,ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(:#{#currentPos.x},:#{#currentPos.y}),4326)) AS \"distance\"" +
          "FROM messages WHERE location && st_makeenvelope(:#{#llb.x}, :#{#llb.y}, :#{#urt.x}, :#{#urt.y}, 4326) ORDER BY distance DESC", nativeQuery = true)
  fun findByLocationWithinBoundingBoxOrderByDistance(@Param("llb") llb: Point,
                                                     @Param("urt") urt: Point,
                                                     @Param("currentPos") currentPos: Point): List<FoundMessage>
}
```

As soon I remove location from my native query everything works fine and location is null in my projection.
My native query also works fine if I return a List of my entity instead of the projection interface.
So the problem is that hibernate is not able to create "org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point" if I use the projecting interface.

Any ideas how to solve it?
Or different approaches?

BR

Comment: did you solve this problem? I have encountered this problem but I haven't found solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

The "no dialect mapping" message usually means that you don't have the correct dialect configured. You need a `SpatialDialect` that register the JDBC mappings for the spatial types. Check the log messages. You should see a `Dialect` with the word "Spatial" in its name.

The problem with Spring-Boot is that it tries to automatically figure out a suitable `Dialect` for your database. But it won't select a `SpatialDialect`. You'll have to manually configure it.